# pcl::Pointcloud to cv::Mat depth image

Tags: c++, opencv, point-cloud-library

I am converting this depth image to a pcl::pointcloud.

[image]

using the following:

```
PointCloud::Ptr PointcloudUtils::RGBDtoPCL(cv::Mat depth_image, Eigen::Matrix3f& _intrinsics)
{
    PointCloud::Ptr pointcloud(new PointCloud);

    float fx = _intrinsics(0, 0);
    float fy = _intrinsics(1, 1);
    float cx = _intrinsics(0, 2);
    float cy = _intrinsics(1, 2);

    float factor = 1;

    depth_image.convertTo(depth_image, CV_32F); // convert the image data to float type 

    if (!depth_image.data) {
        std::cerr << "No depth data!!!" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pointcloud->width = depth_image.cols; //Dimensions must be initialized to use 2-D indexing 
    pointcloud->height = depth_image.rows;
    pointcloud->resize(pointcloud->width*pointcloud->height);

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int v = 0; v < depth_image.rows; v += 4)
    {
        for (int u = 0; u < depth_image.cols; u += 4)
        {
            float Z = depth_image.at<float>(v, u) / factor;

            PointT p;
            p.z = Z;
            p.x = (u - cx) * Z / fx;
            p.y = (v - cy) * Z / fy;

            p.z = p.z / 1000;
            p.x = p.x / 1000;
            p.y = p.y / 1000;

            pointcloud->points.push_back(p);

        }
    }

    return pointcloud;

}
```

this works great, I have run some processing on the cloud, and now I need to convert the pointcloud back to a cv::Mat depth image. I cannot find an example for this, and am having trouble getting m head around it. What is the opposite of the above function?

How can i convert a pcl::pointcloud back to a cv::mat?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the `p.x, p.y,p.z` to represent one float pixel?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I think so, yes. Basically I want to end up with the image above. Same number of cols / rows.

Comment: ... The goal is to reverse the above function. So to go from image to pointcloud, then back to exactly the same image. Thanks!

Comment: Editing the code. I've a question. Why are you incrementing the loop variables by 4?

Comment: Ah sorry, that was to test downsampling. i have replaced it with `++` i am trying your new code, and it looks as though it should work! But I still get a black image. I am testing various settings to try and nail it down. thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can you print the original `depth_image.channels()` and `depth_image.type()` before any kind of conversion occurs?

Comment: Type = 2, channels = 1;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156645/discussion-between-zindarod-and-anti).

Answer (score 1):

This is untested code, since I don't have point cloud on my machine.
From your own conversion code I am assuming your image a single channel image.

```
void PCL2Mat(PointCloud::Ptr pointcloud, cv::Mat& depth_image, int original_width, int original_height)
{
    if (!depth_image.empty())
        depth_image.release();

    depth_image.create(original_height, original_width, CV_32F);

    int count = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int v = 0; v < depth_image.rows; ++v)
    {
        for (int u = 0; u < depth_image.cols; ++u)
        {
            depth_image.at<float>(v, u) = pointcloud->points.at(count++).z * 1000;

        }
    }

    depth_image.convertTo(depth_image,CV_8U);

}
```

Comment: Thank you! i am running this with: `PCL2Mat(newCloud, newDepth, depth_image.cols, depth_image.rows, depth_image.channels());`` and it gives me a black image.

Comment: Well I don't have PointCloud and I don't know what processes you perform on pointcloud data so I can't help you any further. But this code should show you the basics of converting from PCL to Mat.

Comment: this is when converting straight back, without processing, for testing purposes. Could It be the channels? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about OpenCV methods, but in case you do something that makes your point cloud unstructured your process could be something like this

```
% rescale the points by 1000
p.x = p.x * 1000; p.y = p.y * 1000; p.z = p.z * 1000;

% project points on image plane and correct center point + factor
 image_p.x = ( p.x * fx / p.z  -cf ) * factor;
 image_p.y = ( p.y * fy / p.z  -cy ) * factor;
```

Now depending on what you have done with the point cloud the points might not map exactly to image matrix pixel center points (or top left corner for some applications) or you might be missing points -> NaN/0 value pixels. How you process that is up to you, but the most simple way would be to cast image_p.x and image_p.y as integers, make sure they are withing image boundaries and set

```
depth_image.at<float>(image_p.y, image_p.x) = p.Z;`
```

Comment: wouldn't the points be in order? can't they just go in a loop and assign the z values?